# install watir-webdriver always fails

Tags: watir-webdriver

My

```
$ sudo gem install watir-webdriver --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

always fails with following error

(I am running Fedora 17, 64-bit, and have ruby-devel installed)

```
------------------------
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
...........
ERROR:  Error installing watir-webdriver:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Looks like you do not have build tools installed. Maybe this could help: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=184578

Comment: Thanks. This along with other hack helped :)

Comment: Have you installed the `ffi` gem?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544754/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-installing-compass , you shoud install gcc, json_pure, that's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to:
https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1854

abhi7 commented on Oct 21, 2014

abhi7's solution works for my case

xcode-select --install

sudo gem update --system