# Failed to build gem native extension (installing Compass)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, compass-sass

When I attempt to install the latest version of compass (https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0.alpha.17), I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 ERROR:  Error installing compass:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... yes
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_closure()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling AbstractMemory.c
compiling ArrayType.c
compiling Buffer.c
compiling Call.c
Call.c:303:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    rbffi_thread_blocking_region(call_blocking_function, data, (void *) -1, NULL);
    ^
./Thread.h:78:39: note: expanded from macro 'rbffi_thread_blocking_region'
# define rbffi_thread_blocking_region rb_thread_call_without_gvl
                                      ^
1 warning generated.
compiling ClosurePool.c
compiling DataConverter.c
DataConverter.c:43:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling DynamicLibrary.c
compiling ffi.c
compiling Function.c
Function.c:479:33: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'VALUE (void *)' to parameter of type 'void *(*)(void *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        rb_thread_call_with_gvl(callback_with_gvl, &cb);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Function.c:102:46: note: passing argument to parameter 'func' here
extern void *rb_thread_call_with_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1);
                                             ^
Function.c:563:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_thread_call_without_gvl(async_cb_wait, &w, async_cb_stop, &w);
        ^
Function.c:738:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
3 warnings generated.
compiling FunctionInfo.c
compiling LastError.c
compiling LongDouble.c
compiling MappedType.c
compiling MemoryPointer.c
compiling MethodHandle.c
compiling Platform.c
compiling Pointer.c
compiling Struct.c
compiling StructByReference.c
compiling StructByValue.c
compiling StructLayout.c
compiling Thread.c
compiling Type.c
compiling Types.c
compiling Variadic.c
linking shared-object ffi_c.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [ffi_c.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

What's going on here? How do I install the latest compass without error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Comment: please make sure you have make on your system.

Answer (score 606):

Try this, then try to install compass again

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: This fixes the error on Ubuntu, but it seems OP is using OSX.

Comment: Fixed for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Worked on CentOS with "yum install ruby-devel" which is the equivalent. Thanks !

Comment: Funny to find a solution to my Ubuntu problem in an answer to an OSx question. Nevertheless, you’ve got my upvote as your answer just solved my problem. Tnx!

Comment: Worked for me on raspberry pi, Raspbian

Comment: I was having an issue with a specific Gem. However this is fixed it for me. I didn't think of trying this as it was installing other Gems. Incase anyone else comes across the same issue...

Comment: `sudo zypper in ruby-devel` for openSUSE Leap

Comment: I think installing ruby-dev helped, but I also had to install gcc & make.  The errors are not very clear about that.

Comment: Fedora: `sudo dnf install ruby-devel`

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work on Windows?  I installed the Ruby dev tools using `choco install ruby2.devkit` but it's still not working

Comment: rhel-atomic (7.x): `microdnf install --enablerepo=rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms install rh-ruby25 rh-ruby25-ruby-devel`

Answer (score 143):

In order to install compass On Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)had to perform the following:

**1. Set Up Ruby Environment**

- Ensure ruby is installed and up to date: `ruby -v`
- Update gem's `sudo gem update --system`

**2. Set Up MAC Environment**

Install the **Xcode Command Line Tools** this is the key to install Compass.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Installing the Xcode Command Line Tools are the key to getting Compass working on OS X

**3. Install Compass**

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: For me this was exactly the right answer, it needs the Xcode command line tools

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, you are right, the Xcode Command Line Tools are the key.

Comment: This worked for me with one addition - you have to actually start XCODE so that you can accept the license agreement and let it finish setup.  Might be worth tagging onto your answer.

Comment: Accepting the update(terms of agreement) through the GUI worked also.

Comment: On a recently updated MacBook Pro to Sierra 10.12.6, I also had to run "sudo xcodebuild -license" to accept terms and conditions, before running sudo gem install compass....

Comment: Works, but I had to update my path to use the new ruby version

Answer (score 48):

The best way is `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass` to install compass.

Comment: Wow, sometimes it's so easy ^^ tried to install compass with gem, but there were some dependencies not resolved by gem. With apt-get it worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 39):

You can try in Debian with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-dev rubygems compass
```

for Fedora, Centos

```
yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems compass
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I also had to install `make`.

Comment: `ruby-dev` did the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby

Answer (score 30):

I struggled with you same issue for about 3 hours. As of `Compass 1.0.alpha19`, the requirement is for the rvm version 1.9.3.

There are several uncollected posts, however what worked for me was the following:

1. `sudo gem uninstall sass`
2. `sudo gem uninstall compass`
3. `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p448`
4. `sudo gem install sass --pre`
5. `sudo gem install compass --pre`

and that did it. Hope it works for you as well!

Comment: I recently had the same issue but with a newer version. What I did is to uninstall the ruby version I installed previously with aptitude and then I installed it again with following the instructions at: http://rvm.io/rvm/install. With the new ruby/rvm version compass built properly.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. I changed step 3 to `rvm install ruby-2.1.2` as 1.9.3 is no longer being updated

Answer (score 25):

For me to solve this issue, I had to make sure I had the most current version of Ruby and the gems `gem update --system`; then, I had to make sure that Xcode & the Command Line Tools were installed: `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: `xcode-select --install` was done but this doesn't solve it for me

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Ubuntu, you should try install build-essential

```
apt install build-essential
```

I had troubles with gems installation on fresh installation of ubuntu, and this solution worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem. Some more people should upvote this.

Comment: This is the answer for me.

Answer (score 15):

On Mac OS you need to install this feature!

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: macOS 11.2 BigSur trying to install `sudo gem install compass` with OP error. Installing xcode fixed it and I can finally install compass. Mucha gracias!

Answer (score 11):

Hi it was a challenge to get it work on Mac so anyway here is a solution

1. Install [macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Install [rvm](https://rvm.io)
3. Restart Terminal
4. Run `rvm requirements` then run `rvm install 2.1`
5. And last step to run `gem install compass --pre`

I'm not sure but ruby version on Mavericks doesn't support native extensions etc... so if you point to other ruby version like I did "2.1" it works fine.

Comment: I would recommend not using macports.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why none of these are marked as the correct answer, but I landed here through a google search, so I will pass along what I know...

@paul_g's method was pretty close for me, my steps on a Mac osx10.9 Retina:

- Install macports
- Install rvm (stable with ruby add `--insecure` flag for SSL related issues) $`\curl -sSL --insecure https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`
- Restart Terminal / Resource your profile
- Run `rvm requirements --with-gcc=clang` You won't have to update Ruby because you downloaded the last stable version
- And last step to run `gem install compass --pre`

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

Answer (score 5):

For Mac OS:

My error was I forgot to select option in XCode - Preferences - Locations - Command Line Tools after new XCode installation (I had 2 versions and later I deleted one). Maybe it will help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could need to install Apple's Command Line Tools, which probably aren't installed on your system by default. I was getting the same error, but before following any of the instructions here I installed Command Line Tools (due to an unrelated issue) and lo and behold compass installed without issue when I tried again. YMMV.

Comment: This solved the above issue for me, so I would say this is an acceptable answer to the above question.

Answer (score 4):

In order to install Compass on Yosemite you need to set up the Ruby environment and to install the Xcode Command Line Tools.
But, most important thing, after updating Xcode, **be sure to launch the Xcode application and accept the Apple license terms**. It will complete the installation of the components.
After that, you can install Compass: sudo gem install compass

Answer (score 4):

For macOS 10.14 Mojave, make sure you have already installed command line tools via `xcode-select --install` and the run the following command to install std headers.

```
sudo open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Now try your command again.

Answer (score 3):

you must have **gcc,json_pure**

i collect some information from several post

```html
sudo gem uninstall sass
sudo gem uninstall compass
sudo gem update --system
gem install json_pure   (if you have already have continued to next step)
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++   (if you have already have continued to next step)
sudo gem install sass

sudo gem install compass
```

Hi if ** sudo gem update --system ** not working you got an error in the update then  use

sudo gem update --system 2.7.8

Comment: I also had to run `sudo yum install -y redhat-rpm-config` for Fedora 24 before installing compass because of this error: `gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory`

Comment: `sudo gem update --system` gave me errors: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM) Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem` :(

Answer (score 2):

On yosemite, all you must do is install the command line tools. then it works.

Even if other gems installed fine.  You must run xcode-select --install  for gem install compass to work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X 10.9, if you try `xcode-select --install`, you will get the following error :

> Can't install the software because it is not currently available from
>   the Software Update server.

The solution is to download Command Line Tools (OS X 10.9) directly from Apple website : https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-

You will then be able to install the last version of Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 14.04, while execute *apt-get install rubygems*, there is a error

> E: Package 'rubygems' has no installation candidate

follow command solve the problems.

> sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-devel  rubygems-integration ruby-compass

Answer (score 2):

**Try `brew install coreutils`.**

I've hit this problem while rebuilding an aging sass/compass project that was recently updated to ruby 2.2.5 by a colleague. The project uses rvm and bundler.   These were my commands

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.2.5
$ rvm use ruby-2.2.5
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install
```

This caused me to hit the famed `ffi` installation errors, that are reported around the StackOverflow environment:

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Most of the suggestions to solve this problem are to install Xcode command line tools. However this was already installed in my environment:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Other suggestions said to install gcc... so I tried:

```
$ brew install gcc46
```

But this also failed due to a segmentation fault... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

So, I then tried installing compass by hand, just to see if it would give the same `ffi` error:

```
$ gem install compass
```

But to my surprise, I got a totally different error:

```
make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
```

So I searched for that issue, and found [this ancient blog post](http://thoughtsthatleakedout.blogspot.com/2011/10/problem-with-gmkdir-when-updating-gems.html) that said to install coreutils:

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

After installing `coreutils` with Homebrew, bundler was able to finish and installed compass and dependencies successfully.

The End.

Answer (score 2):

when

> gem install overcommit

is run  also this error have been placed in terminal.

```
Failed to build gem native extension
```

please do the same

```
xcode-select --install
```

and it will fix that issue too

Comment: I get `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. This doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, then try to install compass again

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint but I was able to fix it by uninstalling ruby and install it again.

**Uninstall ruby:**

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

It reported some ruby packages like:

```
Package 'ruby' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libruby2.2 ruby-chunky-png ruby-sass rubygems-integration
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

**Uninstall remaining packages***

```
apt-get autoremove
```

**Install ruby again**

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2
```

**Install Compass**

```
sudo gem install compass
```

The last command was executed with success.

Answer (score 0):

for me it happened after a xcode software update.

had to execute:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

as after an update you need to "agree" again to xcode license

Answer (score -1):

Installing Ruby gems on a Mac is a common source of confusion and frustration. Unfortunately, most solutions are incomplete, outdated, and provide bad advice. The answer here with the most votes says to use `sudo` which you should never need to do, especially if you don't understand what it does.

Learn [why you should never use sudo to install gems](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=22544754).

It is correct that the error "Failed to build gem native extension" is due to the Apple command line tools not being installed. However, installing them won't necessarily provide you with a proper Ruby environment.

At a high level, there are 5 steps to a working Ruby setup, which I've written about in detail in my [definitive guide to installing Ruby gems on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=22544754). It explains why you are getting this error, compares the various solutions, why some are better than others, and why you shouldn't use `sudo`.

I've also written about these steps in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191