# compass not working with mithril yeoman generator

Tags: sass, compass-sass, yeoman, compass, mithril.js

I am trying to run the [Mithril yeoman generator](https://github.com/hung-phan/generator-mithril) unfortunately it falls over on *grunt serve* with the error

**Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task Warning: Couldn't find the compass binary. Make sure it's installed ...**

I can of course use --force to continue and it works fine but the css is not included which is a bit pointless, and my next option would be to modify the gruntfile to only use Sass without Compass.

Note I have tried of the following suggestions from this [issue log for grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/66):

```
npm install grunt-contrib-compass
sudo gem install sass
sudo gem install compass
```

Thanks

Comment: Steven, the issue you mentioned would seem like the ideal place to ask for this – the people there are more likely to have relevant insights because they'll probably have tried similar things. I tried to run the Yeoman generator but it broke during install. I succeeded in installing it by playing with the options, but then when I tried to run it it failed trying to load a resource it hadn't installed. The maintainers and users of the repo will probably have more patience with these kinds of blockers which make it difficult to reproduce your error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it would be the logical place to ask, just none of the answers worked and there was a lot of noise on that post. I found the actual fix in the end on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544754/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-installing-compass)

In order to install compass On Mac OS X (Yosemite)

**Set Up Ruby Environment, ensure its up to date**

```
ruby -v
sudo gem update --system
```

**Set Up MAC Environment, install Xcode Command Line Tools**

```
xcode-select --install
```

*This was the key to getting Compass working on OS X!*

**Install Sass**

```
sudo gem install sass
```

**Install Compass**

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: Compass install page doesn't tell you to use sudo but I kept getting Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary without it http://compass-style.org/install/