# listener.rb: Not a directory

Tags: compass-sass

In the past few week, I've started seeing errors when I try to run compass watch:

Errno::ENOTDIR on line ["60"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-2.8.0/lib/listen/listener.rb: Not a directory - /Users/nick/.compass/extensions/readme.txt/stylesheets

It will watch and compile the SCSS into CSS once and then I have to run compass watch again and get that error. When I run compass watch --trace, I get this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1cia842dusitol/compass-watch-trace.png?dl=0

My versions are Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris) & Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option I found was this: [Failed to build gem native extension (installing Compass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544754/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-installing-compass/22887946#22887946)

After that, I starting using http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/ and that worked fine. When I started a new job that uses Grunt, I ditched `compass watch` all together and used the grunt-contrib-sass plug-in to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running compass watch in terminal because I was in the wrong directory. Are you running it in the same directory as the config.rb file is located at?

I fixed it by first navigating to the folder config.rb is in and then executing compass watch...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually pointing to that directory and getting this error. Since then, I reinstalled previous versions of Sass, Compass and Ruby. That worked for a while and then broke with another Mac OSX update. I then used the Scout 3rd party app. After a while I gave up and have been using Grunt to compile my Sass and I am totally happy with that.