# Jenkins - Fastlane can't find gem fastlane

Tags: macos, jenkins, fastlane

I'm using `Fastlane` one my admin account (Mac OS) and it works great.

I try now to install and configure `Jenkins` + `Fastlane` but when jenkins try to run a fastlane commande, I get that error : `can't find gem fastlane (>= 0.a) with executable fastlane (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`

Path of my fastlane install is : `/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin`

When I try to update fastlane in jenkins account (su jenkins), console say I'm not sudo. No error with my account.

Already tried to inject Path in jenkins conf and to set RVM-managed environment version. But it failed.

Comment: Does the Jenkins user also have it's own `.rvm`? We use `rbenv`, and we make sure that the Jenkins user has that installed and setup on all our Mac CI nodes. I have Jenkins `bundle install` in the project directory before it tries to run `fastlane` to make sure it has everything that it needs.

Is that something you can do?

Comment: Are you running Jenkins with myusername or jenkins user? If the latter, he won't be able to reach your install directory. I would also suggest that you install fastlane in its default folder (/usr/local/bin).

Answer (score 6):

Use anyone of below

## Using RubyGems

```
sudo gem install fastlane -NV
```

## Alternatively using Homebrew

```
brew cask install fastlane
```

See link for reference [link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/)

Comment: I am getting error below while trying sudo gem install fastlane -NV

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544754/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-installing-compass

Comment: Just make sure Ruby installed on your machine. To install ruby use command "apt-get install ruby-dev" or follow this link https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina#ruby

Answer (score 4):

If you using pipeline in jenkins use `sh 'gem install fastlane'`
it works fine.

Comment: This does not help as on mac you have to use - sudo gem install fastlane and that is not the preferred way in CI pipeline environment. Ideally we should be able to set environment.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did to fix a similar bug:

```
gem update bundler
```

Comment: That is correct answer

Answer (score 3):

For me all that needed to be done was `rvm default` and then reinstall what was needed, because for some reason it was installing for the older ruby version and not the newer one, so when it was accessing it on Jenkins, it was checking the new version which had nothing.

Comment: You can check the versions of it used with `gem env`